# How should I fetch `map` column with specific keys in hive query - Impala SQL

Tags: mysql

Requirement: I am dealing with a table like following:

| itemid | genderMap |
| --- | --- |
| 122 | map['female']0.32 |
| 111 | map['male']0.89 |

genderMap is a map structure contains only one key(string), value(float32) is the confidence of the key.
if I only want to fetch the row whose key == 'female' and count the number of them, how should I do this?
my statements: `select count(*) from tab where genderMap.key='female'` but failed

Comment: Map structure is unknown to MySQL. Work with the value like it is a string, use `WHERE LOCATE('map[\'female\']', genderMap)`.

Comment: Sorry, I tried your method, it does not work, in fact, I am working with hive query. I am not sure whether it's the same as mysql

Comment: MySQL is DBMS. Hive is framework, a library, which accesses some DBMS, maybe MySQL. They're not "the same" even in theory.